# Convert Raw SQL Query to Laravel Eloquent left outer join

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

can anyone help me turn the query in to Eloquent?

Model Orders::
Model TaskCard::

```
select 
    ifnull(data, o.created_at) as dataZlecenia,o.id, o.nazwa
from  
    orders o
left outer join
    (select max(created_at) as data,order_id from task_cards
group by order_id) as a 
on a.order_id=o.id
order by dataZlecenia desc
```

Comment: Hey, did you try anything so far?
Please read documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries

Comment: Hey. I tried so. The problem is that I have to have it as a model, not an array. in the models I use function hasmany/hasone

Comment: Add your relationships to the question, it can help us to build your query.

Comment: public function klient()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Customer', 'id', 'klientID')->withTrashed();
    }

Comment: Do you really need the ifnull statement?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have wrong namespace as well, try using `App\ModelName` instead of `App\Models\ModelName`. And use english for naming functions/classes :)

Check if your foreign keys are used correctly. If you want it to work just out of the box, `orders` table should have `client_id` as foreign key and `id` as primary key, while `clients` table has to have primary key `id`. Then this solution will work:

```
public function order(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Order');
}
```

via https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships

EDIT:
for better understanding :) in `create_orders_table` migration:

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('client_id');
$table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Moreover I can't see a reason why your client can have just one order. I'd use in `Client` model:

```
public function orders(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Order');
}
```

And in `Order` model:

```
public function client(){
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Client');
}
```

This way your client will be able to have multiple orders and an order will have just one assigned client.